# I've linked scilab to gnome application menu (by creating a *.desktop file) but it's closed immediately when I run it from menu

Tags: .desktop, appmenu, scilab

I have downloaded `scilab` and extracted it to `/home/user/apps/scilab-6.0.1/`. There isn't any problem executing from command line and `scilab` runs perfect after I type the following command:

```
~/user/apps/scilab-6.0.1/bin/scilab
```

To link `scilab` to the gnome application menu and favorite apps, I've created the following `scilab.desktop` file in the path `/usr/share/applications/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Scientific software package for numerical computations
Exec=/home/user/apps/scilab-6.0.1/bin/scilab %f
GenericName=Scientific Software Package
Icon=/home/user/apps/scilab-6.0.1/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/scilab.png
Name=Scilab
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Science;Math;
```

The `scilab` icon appeared in the menu as a result, but when I click on it, it opens and closes immediately. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You have `Exec=/home/user/apps/scilab-6.0.1/bin/scilab %f`, maybe `scilab` expects a file to read (`%f` expands to the filename passed as an argument)?

Comment: @MrShunz I've tried without '%f' or with any other like '%d,%D, ...' but not working yet!

Comment: what happens if you call the binary directly from a terminal?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you already tried from the command line. It might be it needs a terminal to work, try configuring `Terminal=true` in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Thanks. changing `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true` keeps scilab open. please add it to your answer. Now is there any way to close terminal while kipping scilab open?

Comment: I don't think you can close that terminal, as it's the one launching `scilab`. Maybe you can try running scilab in the backgroup (append `&` to the `Exec` string).

Answer (score 0):

I found a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scilab/+bug/1739476) for the exact same problem.

Looks like it's a bug of `scilab` more than a problem with Gnome/Ubuntu.

As a workaround, change your `Exec` command as described:

```
Exec=env LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" xterm -e /home/user/apps/scilab-6.0.1/bin/scilab
```

**EDIT based on comments**

Looks like configuring `Terminal=true` has the same effect and is enough
to keep `scilab` open.